# Windows XP - screen turns off after X time

Tags: windows, windows-xp, display, power-management

I have a Windows XP PC that's supposed to stay on without closing the screen etc. Even if the setting is set to `never`, after a while the screen shuts down no matter what I chose.

Any idea?

Comment: Take a watch and time exactly how long it takes for screen to go blank. Also, is there anything you can do to make things appear on the screen again?  There are different possibilities for screen to go blank.  Sleep. Suspend. Power off.   Blank Screensaver.  Loss of output to screen.   Another thing you can try is VNC or lacking that then remote desktop..Supposing you have VNC installed and tested it to see if it works reliably, then, (eg if you can VNC when the screen goes blank, then that's different to if you can't)

Comment: The term "the setting is set to never" is lacking details. Which setting? In the bios? In the XP energy settings? In a third party software?

Comment: hello power option  in windows power setting not in bios

Answer (score 1):

Use a third-party tool such as [Caffeine](https://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/), [Don't Sleep](https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Microsoft/DontSleep) or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/browse/search/?q=caffeine). They generally act by simulating a keypress or reporting a very important task that cannot be interrupted. Of course, check that the application is compatible with lab software.

You might also consider switching OS, if feasible, to one that's still supported. (A location where I worked kept Windows 3.1 running on one PC until well into Windows 8's reign, but finally chose to use new software!)

Comment: hello  thanks for that it's impossible to switch OS because ethe lap pc is ruining an old device and cannot be change we have 2 pc and 2 device de same and one of them is not acting like that and power setting are identical

Comment: @PierreAuger If so then DON'T have it online, EVER!